# multiple upstream groups in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

Nginx beginner's questions: are multiple `upstream` definitions allowed in the config, e.g:

```
  upstream backendA {
    server host1:443;
  }

  upstream backendB {
    server host2:443;
  }

  location addrA {
    https://backendA/;
  }

  location addrB {
    https://backendB/;
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but your example is incorrect, as `upsteam` statements go into the `http` or `stream` block and `location` statements go into a `server` or another `location` block.

Comment: thank you @RichardSmith